# How to perform power() function on RGB matrix in matlab

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matlab-figure

In a project, I need to perform power() function on RGB matrix in a matlab GUI program, but matlab keeps returning error meesage. 
Below is the code and the error message

```
img_src = getappdata(handles.figure_pjimage, 'img_src');
R=img_src(:,:,1);
G=img_src(:,:,2);
B=img_src(:,:,3);
C = 12;
gamma = 0.8;
R1 = C * power(R, gamma);
G1 = C * power(G, gamma);
B1 = C * power(B, gamma);
R2 = power((R1 / C), (1/gamma));
G2 = power((G1 / C), (1/gamma));
B2 = power((B1 / C), (1/gamma));
disp(max(R2));
new_img = cat(3,R2,G2,B2);
axes(handles.axes_dst);
imshow(new_img);
```

And here is the error message

```
Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.
```

However, when I try to use power() function in command window, this can be done.

```
>> A = [2,2
2,2]

A =

     2     2
     2     2

>> power(A,0.4)

ans =

    1.3195    1.3195
    1.3195    1.3195
```

Please tell me if any of you get the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your RGB-matrices are e.g. in format `uint8` or `uint16`, as this is the output format of image import functions for a lot of file types. As `power` intends not to violate the format definition, which it would for fractional powers, it throws the error.

So basically you only have to change lines 2-4 to:

```
R = double( img_src(:,:,1) );
G = double( img_src(:,:,2) );
B = double( img_src(:,:,3) );
```

and your code should work as desired.

Comment: And can you tell me why img_src(:,:,1) can return the channel of color Red

Comment: What do you mean with "why"? RGB images are stacked 2D-matrices. There are 3 layers, one for red, green and blue. With `img_src(:,:,1)` you adress the first layer, therefore red. There can also be a 4th layer for informations about transparency (alpha map).

Comment: "format `uint8`, as this is the standard output format of the image import functions". This is not true. The class of the read image is defined on the image file, there's no Matlab standard for that. It simply happens that most people only deal with `uint8` images but you may get an image with any class including floating point complex numbers. Also, there will be no 4th layer for transparency. The alpha channel is returned as a separate output argument for `imread`.

Comment: @carandraug you're right, I usually don't deal with images and just had a short glance at the doc. And the alpha channel is a 4th layer, I know that it is stored in a separate variable, but that does not matter regarding my statement, which had nothing to do with matlab really.

Comment: @thewaywewalk when the subject is images in Matlab, after saying that one access the 1st layer with `img_src(:,:,1)` and that there can be a 4th layer for alpha channel, sounded like you're saying that one can access it with `img_src(:,:,4)` which would be incorrect. The value 4 in the 3rd dimension is for the black channel in case the image is CMYK.